# Android Studio - Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' - java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, exception, android-studio, gradle, build

Lately nine out of ten of my builds fail with the following exception. I clean and rebuild the project, but to no avail. I have searched everywhere and tried the solutions shared on other similar questions - again no help. My Android Studio version is 2.0 Beta 5 with Gradle also at 2.0.0-beta5. Here is the exception that I receive:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 14 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:424)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:119)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:364)
... 26 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1443)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibraryNoCache(AndroidBuilder.java:1633)
at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:119)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1588)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:474)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:428)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1427)
... 5 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$2.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1435)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$2.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1427)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
... 2 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.043 secs
```

Could anyone please provide any clues?

EDIT: Most other similar questions have answers suggesting there are conflicting dependencies, so here is my dependency tree. I don't see a conflict. Anything?:

```
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
+--- project :circularreveal      
|    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
\--- project :ColorPickerPreference
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to Java 1.8 and this issues should go away. I do not know exactly what cause the: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` but upgrading to `Java 1.8` has always fixed it for me.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'

Comment: Upgraded, still didn't help.

Comment: After doing a little research your Exception is different than the one I have faced in the past. First run a gradle clean then try running your task this way gradle <task> --no-daemon --max-workers=1 --rerun-tasks -S -i --recompile-scripts  replacing <task> with your task.

Comment: What am I going to accomplish with that command? Is it something to fix the problem or am I going to get more info on the error?

Comment: Both. You are turning off a lot of gradles optimizations which might fix your issue. Secondly, your telling it clean and rerun everything which might clear out some bad cache. Third then --info will make gradle tell you every single action it takes. It will give you a mount of info which on the down side can be hard to use, but hopefully it will be enough to tell you what subtask is failing which is causing the ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' task to fail. edit: -i is the same as --info.

Comment: Thanks. --no-daemon was not recognized as a command option, so I removed that. It built successfully 3 out of 4 times now. The one time it did not, I got this exception:

    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: java.lang.NullPointerException","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\njava.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:313)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:415)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)\n\tat ........

Comment: Run these: gradle --version  java -version  javac -version  echo JAVA_HOME  My best guess as to your problem is version conflicts or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118057/android-studio-when-i-add-a-java-module-in-app-it-will-be-wrong Btw, in your question you said Gradle 2.0.0-beta5. Gradle 2.0 is very old, currently it is on 2.11. I dont think you are really running 2.0, but I could be wrong.

Comment: After using --max-workers once or twice the problem has disappeared. I don't use --max-workers anymore. Also I have updated to 2.0 beta 6 and not seeing the problem anymore.

Comment: Tried the same, but did not work for me. Having the exact same error when running connectedAndroidTest task. Gradle 2.11, gradle plugin beta6. The exception is thrown when dexing play-services-base is done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd got the same exception and it was fixed after I cleaned the project(Build->Clean Project). Try it.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably an issue with less RAM available while I was trying to compile my project. Once I freed up memory it was fixed automatically.